# Why are multiple Ruby processes on an EC2 server causing 100% CPU utilisation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, puma

I have a Rails application which has 100% CPU utilization most of the time.
I am not able to figure out why there is so much load on the server. I am using the Puma web server with a default configuration, and am running multiple background jobs using the [sucker-punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch) gem. There are 7 files which are using sucker punch jobs with 5 workers:

```
include SuckerPunch::Job 
workers 5
```

I ran the `top -i` query and found the following processes running on the server. I can see multiple Ruby commands on the server. Can someone tell me whether this is normal behavior on a server, or if something is wrong?

[image: output of "top" command]

Comment: I'm not sure what application server are you using and it's config. I think you have to many workers configured. You have to provide more information about the app server (puma? passenger? unicorn?)

Comment: I am using Puma app server, and I am also using sucker punch gem for multiple background jobs

Comment: So, what is the config for Puma? how many workers are you using? and what about the sucker_punch config? It seems you have too many workers on both

Comment: I am using default PUMA configuration on AWS EC2 server and default sucker-punch configuration.

But There are 7 files on which are using sucker punch job with 5 workers each.

I have added details on the question itself for better readability

Comment: run `top -c`, it adds a column with more info of the command that created each process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some Ways to Reduce Resource Contention

Your user space load is high (~48%), so you'll probably want to reduce the number of workers in your web application, increase the number of CPUs available on your instance, move to a version of Ruby that has better concurrency and real multi-core support (e.g. Rubinius or JRuby), or some combination of these options. Depending on what your code is actually doing, you may also need to re-architect your application to offload expensive I/O from the application server.

In addition, your steal time is quite high (~41%), so your EC2 instance is probably overloaded. Simply moving your application to a less-loaded instance may free up sufficient resources to reduce application wait times.

Comment: Thanks Todd. Your insight about user space and steal time helped to look into a direction which reduced CPU utilazation.